# how to input n numbers and print it in ascending order without using array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I was trying to create a program that takes `n` number of input in a loop and capable of showing output in ascending order. The main theme of program is **it should not use** arrays.

I tried it by creating a program that takes input and shows smallest number first then 2nd smallest and 3rd smallest and so on. But I am new to programming so my program could do only like 1st smallest and it does not work.


I also saw heap data structure in one of the similar questions but couldn't figure out how it can work without arrays.

Please help me how can we use heap data structure or give me a good suggestion to do it.

Comment: Why can't you use arrays?

Comment: It should not use arrays in what way? Storing the numbers? Sorting the numbers?

Comment: both storing and sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number, -1 to exit: ");
    int num = scanner.nextInt();

    if (num == -1) break;

    list.add(num);
}

// sort the list (ascending)
Collections.sort(list);

// output the list
for (Integer val : list) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well you certainly are a real skeptic!

Comment: Um, an ArrayList is fundamentally just an array with an Object on top. Does this *really* qualify?

Comment: Switched to `LinkedList`.  Not sure what the OP is really looking for.  I _suspected_ that his assignment is just to use some sort of collection rather than an explicit array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Streams:

```
    StreamSupport.stream(
            Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new Scanner(System.in), Spliterator.ORDERED),
            false)
            .limit(10)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SortedSet for default sorting, without duplicates. (Don't if duplicates are needed here!)

```
    SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number, -1 to exit: ");
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        if (num == -1) 
            break;
        sortedSet.add(num);
    }
    System.out.println(sortedSet);
```